# Monkey patch Django runserver command

Tags: python, django

I want to add `--env=prod/beta/alpha/dev` to `runserver` so i can do `python manage.py runserver --env=prod` for example.

I've tried to add to `settings.py`:

```
parser = CommandParser(None)
parser.add_argument('--env')
parser.add_argument('args', nargs='*')  # catch-all

try:
    options, args = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv[2:])
except CommandError:
    pass  # Ignore any option errors at this point.

APP_ENV = options.env or 'dev'
```

But I got:

```
usage: manage.py runserver [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                       [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                       [--traceback] [--no-color] [--ipv6] [--nothreading]
                       [--noreload] [--nostatic] [--insecure]
                       [addrport]
manage.py runserver: error: unrecognized arguments: --env=beta
```

Any idea how can I monkey patch `runserver`?

Comment: I hope you are aware that `runserver` is [not suitable for production deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port).

Answer (score 1):

To modify runserver, you could create a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/). You should be able to subclass runserver and add the extra arguments.

You might find it easier to set an environment variable, rather than changing the runserver command. In your settings, you would do something like:

```
import os
env = os.getenv('ENV') or 'dev'
```

Then you would run the dev server with

```
ENV=dev python manage.py runserver
```